# Getting Undefined Error While trying To Run a JS Code

Tags: javascript

```
var i = 0;

function clickPlay(){
    var playButtons = $('.player-play');
    playButtons[i].click();
    i++;
}

function playVideos() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        clickPlay();
        playVideos();
    }, 5000); // Change this value to speed up or slow down the time interval
}

playVideos();
```

This should play every video on a page , but everytime i run it i get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
    at clickPlay (<anonymous>:5:16)
    at <anonymous>:11:9
```

It plays the first video and nothing more. Im a noob at JS but i'll try everything you say. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why not simply use `$.each` and add the timeout inside the loop?

Comment: What happens when you go past the number of videos you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any limit for that loop, so you're not controlling the range of the array.

Better use `jQuery.each`:

```
function playVideos() {
    $('.player-play').each(function () {
       var _this = $(this);
       setTimeout(function () {
           _this.click();
       }, 5000);
    });
}

playVideos();
```